# Canonical Example of how to test Akka Actor using Scala in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, scalatest, specs2

Having created an Akka actor in Play Framework, I now want to test it. However I immediately hit a problem:

1. The current [Play Scala Testing](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTest) page contains nothing about testing Actors and uses Specs2 for all examples
2. I could find no actor test examples in the Play 2.2.1 source tests, or in the samples (which also use Specs2).
3. The [Akka actor test page](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html) uses ScalaTest, and the Akka system setup appears different from that used by the Play application itself.
4. The Akka actor test does discuss workarounds for problems using Specs2, but without providing a worked example of such a test, and certainly not one using Play's built-in test fixtures.

Can anyone provide a canonical example of testing an Akka actor using TestKit and Play's test fixtures?

For consistency's sake I would prefer it to use Specs2 (frankly, it seems bizarre to require two different testing frameworks for a single app) however I will accept a ScalaTest example if it integrates well with the Play test fixtures.

Comment: "Play Scala Testing" link is broken:
https://playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTest

Comment: Yes they've now added ScalaTest documentation as well for Play 2.2 and later.

Comment: The [Play Scala Testing](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaTest) link still works for 2.1.x but has moved to [Testing your Application with Specs2](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithSpecs2) for 2.2.x and later.
However the [new test pages](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingYourApplication) provide examples for [ScalaTest](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithScalaTest) as well, and render this question redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is really nothing special to it, you basically just have tests that looks like the actor samples but using the specs2 test syntax instead. If you want to use the akka test utilities you will have to add an explicit dependency on it from your build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.2.0" % "test"
)
```

Then there is nothing special to it, except that you cannot inherit TestKit on the test class since Specification also is a class and there are name classes. This is an example of how you could use a custom Scope for using TestKit:

```
import org.specs2.specification.Scope

class ActorSpec extends Specification {

  class Actors extends TestKit(ActorSystem("test")) with Scope

  "My actor" should {

     "do something" in new Actors {
       val actor = system.actorOf(Props[SomeActor])

       val probe = TestProbe()
       actor.tell("Ping", probe.ref)
       probe.expectMsg("Pong")
     }

    "do something else" in new Actors { new WithApplication {
      val actor = system.actorOf(Props[SomeActorThatDependsOnApplication])

      val probe = TestProbe()
      actor.tell("Ping", probe.ref)
      probe.expectMsg("Pong")
    }}

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's not compiling for me at the moment, giving a `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.specs2.execute.AsResult` error. I'll try and chase it down in the morning.

Comment: OK, yes. That was an imports problem: `Scope` should be `org.specs2.specification.Scope` not `akka.actor.Scope`.

Comment: `in new Actors` by itself (without `new WithApplication`) gives `There is no started application akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: exception during creation`
Is there any scenario where the actor could be tested without starting the application? (e.g. is the first test a valid scenario?)
Works perfectly when also using WithApplication, BTW.

Comment: This depends on what you do in your actor, if you avoid touching anything that depends on Application the actor can be tested standalone (you could make sure of this by never importing play.api.Play.current in the actor scope). One way of achieving this is DI - provide any setting to a props factory method and only use the play configuration where you create the actor in the app for example.

Comment: I see. So I should use Play's version of implicits (such as ExecutionContext) within the Application itself (to use the Play app configuration), but can test the Actors stand-alone if I use the Akka implicits?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good strategy to get a loosely coupled and easily testable application.